# Reducing the time and space complexity of these functions

Tags: c#, time-complexity, space-complexity

Here I generate a random number from a list.

```
/////somecode///////
        randNum = new Random();
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        List1 = new List<double>();
 /////somecode///////   

public int func1()
{
    double rand = randNum.NextDouble();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in Dictionary)
    {
        if (randomNum <= List1[index])
        {
            return item.Key;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1 ;
}
```

And here I give a pairList as a parameter to add it's keys and values to the Dictionary1.

```
    public void func2(List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pairList)
    {
        foreach (var item in pairList)
        {
            if (Dictionary1.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out double value))
            {
                Dictionary1.Remove(item.Key);
                sum -= value;
                SumList.Remove(sum);
            }
            Dictionary1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item.Key, item.Value));
            Sum += item.Value;
            SumList.Add(_cdfSum);
        }
    }
```

How can I reduce the time and space complexity of these functions?

Comment: Are you asking because you are running into performance problems?  Your code seems more or less efficient to me.  Not sure why you think you need to optimize.

Comment: These will be a part of a huge project, and every time I sent a PR, I get some feedback to improve the code in the means of complexities like why didn't you use binary search, etc. So I thought I should search deeper this time..

Comment: Really unclear what this code is supposed to do so how can we help you more than you can yourself? Things I can see: why remove from the dictionary only to re-add? Just `TryGetValue` then replace it, by using `Dictionary1[item.key] = item.Value;` and if you really wanted to remove it, you can use the `Remove` overload which returns the value as an `out` parameter

Comment: @noobico hopefully your organization is sufficiently collegial that you can just ask your reviewers to elaborate?

Comment: In func1 I see there is a coupling between Dictionary and List1. I guess you omitted some logic here, so I can only guess your intent. If you elaborate on your intent I guess you could get input on what to improve.